# Using Jackson to deserialize array nested within array in JSON object

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson to deserialize a JSON string into an object. I have an object similar to below

```
@Data
public class Party {

    protected String partyType;
    protected List<Field> fields;

}
```

To deserialize this party object I have a mixin class which works as follows

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
abstract class PartyMixin {

@JsonCreator
PartyMixin(@JsonProperty("partyType") String partyType) {}

        @JsonProperty("fields")  
    @JsonDeserialize(using=FieldListDeserializer.class) List<Field> fields;

    private static final class FieldListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Field>>  {
    public List<Field> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return DeserializationUtils.deserializeFromDataNode(jp, ctxt, "field", new TypeReference<List<Field>>() {});
    }
}
}
```

with the deserializeFromDataNode method looking like

```
public static <T> T deserializeFromDataNode(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, String propertyName, TypeReference<T> typeReference) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (jp.hasCurrentToken() && jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
        JsonNode dataNode = jp.readValueAs(JsonNode.class);
        if (dataNode.has(propertyName)) {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.reader(typeReference).<T>readValue(dataNode.get(propertyName));
        }
        return null;
    }
    throw ctxt.mappingException("Expected JSON object");
}
```

This all works fine and the arrayList gets deserialized into the correct a list of the correct objects. However where I'm getting stuck is in the following scenario where I have a list of parties with each of them then having a list of fields

```
@Data
public class Event {

    protected Integer eventId;
    protected List<Party> parties;
}
```

In this case I get an error when deserializing parties above.

```
 @JsonProperty("parties")  
@JsonDeserialize(using=PartyListDeserializer.class) List<Party> parties;

private static final class PartyListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Party>>  {
    public List<Party> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return DeserializationUtils.deserializeFromDataNode(jp, ctxt, "party", new TypeReference<List<Party>>() {});
    }
}
```

Error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of >START_OBJECT token
>   at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:

I get the reason I'm getting the error - when I'm deserializing the array of objects it doesn't expect one of the nested objects to contain an array. This is where I'm getting stuck as to a tidy reusable way to traverse the JSON and deserialize both a regular object and an array object. The main stumbling block in creating a generic method is how to know the type of the nested array. So in my method above for the first array I pass in the type to the reader. If I change the method to be recursive and to check if the node is an array how do I then infer the type and name from the node?

```
if (dataNode.has(propertyName)) {
    for(JsonNode subNode: dataNode) {
        if (subNode.isArray()) {
    // How to know the type and name from the node to pass it in?
    List<T> subActions = deserializeFromDataNode(jp, ctxt...

    }
    else {
    T value = OBJECT_MAPPER.reader(typeReference).readValue(subNode);
    actions.add(value);
    }
}
return (T) actions;
}
```

Apologies if my explanation above isn't that clear. I figure there has to be a way in Jackson to accomplish this but just can't figure it out. If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Derm

Comment: You did it in really jumbled way. Couldn't you use object mapping using Jackson annotations or something like that? Could you show your exmaple JSON and POJO classes which you have? Maybe we can help you in deserializing JSON in more readable way.